# Python: While loop index out of bounds

Tags: loops, while-loop

After reading answers in many other similar posts I still can't figure out where I'm wrong.

My problem in shorts: I'm converting in Python a code that I already use successfully in both Matlab and R.

Data: I have a dataframe called 'sign' (651x1) with a single column 'Signals'. The only value are: [-1,0,1,nan] . Below an example not following the real order

```
|             |Signals |
|Date         | ---    |
|2018-07-23   | nan    |
|2018-07-24   |1       |
|2018-07-25   |-1      |
|2018-07-26   |0       |
```

Now, I create other 2 tables:
1)'Pos_long' (651x2)                  2)'Pos_short'(651x2)
both filled with 'zeros' for the length of 'sign'. Below an example:

```
|             |Entry   |Exit   |
|0            | 0      |0      |     
|1            | 0      |0      | 
|2            | 0      |0      |
```

My target: I want to create a loop for the whole length of 'sign' with these rules:

- If sign[row] is -1 then I fill table 'Pos_short' this way: first column(Entry) reports the number of the row where I find '-1' while the second column(Exit) report the number of row where I exit the trade which is when I find the first sign[row]=0
- If sign[row] is 1 then I fill table 'Pos_long' following the same criteria for 'Pos_short' above.

So here follow my code:

```
r=0
k=0
while k<=(len(sign)-1):
    if  sign['Signals'][k] == -1:
        Pos_short['Entry'][r]=k
        j=0
        while sign['Signals'][k+j]!=0:
            j+=1
        Pos_short['Exit'][r]=k+j
        k+=j
        r+=1
    k+=1
k=1
```

Explanation: Once I find '-1' I say it to keep going on in counting rows  until I find the first row where I get '0'. At that point it fills both column (Entry and Exit) with respective number of rows.

Unfortunately, unlike Matlab and R, I'm experiencing problems in understanding my index outbounds as the error I get is the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4722         try:
-> 4723             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4724         except KeyError as e1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 651

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-4d023ff81cb1> in <module>
      6         Pos_short['Entry'][r]=k
      7         j=0
----> 8         while sign['Signals'][k+j]!=0:
      9             j+=1
     10         Pos_short['Exit'][r]=k+j

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1062         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
   1063         try:
-> 1064             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
   1065 
   1066             if not is_scalar(result):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py in get_value(self, series, key)
    990 
    991         try:
--> 992             return com.maybe_box(self, Index.get_value(self, series, key), series, key)
    993         except KeyError:
    994             try:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4727 
   4728             try:
-> 4729                 return libindex.get_value_box(s, key)
   4730             except IndexError:
   4731                 raise

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_box()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at()

pandas\_libs\util.pxd in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer()

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I know it has to do with 'k+j' but I really can't figure it out.
Where Am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally get it: the code is fine but BEFORE running it, I had to insert this line:

```
sign.Signals[-1]=0
```

The reason is that a trade (as it was in my case) may be still open at the end of my available data. This means that there is a 'Sell' order (-1) NOT followed YET by a '0' (close order).
This affects the "while/for loop" and put it to exceed its bounds.
Hope it can be useful for someone.